# How to change menu item font size?

Tags: fonts, menu

My Ubuntu 15.04 menu font is much smaller than that of the title bar. I want to make them **the same size**, and I have tried *Ubuntu Tweak* and *Tweak Tools*, but no matter what I change, the size of *default font, desktop font, monospace font, document font, or window title bar font*, the menu font size just keep unchanged. I do not want to adjust the *text scaling factor*, because that has global effects on the system. Dose anyone has the solution?[my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R3NC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the font size of the file manager content windows after connecting my laptop to an external display, messing with screen resolution, then disconnecting it.  To restore proper font proportions, I ran the fc-cache command in a terminal, then logged out and back in (using the gui menu, not just sourcing my .profile from the terminal).

```
fc-cache -rv
```

That fixed the font size for me.